# Using a variable to refer to another variable in Bash

Tags: bash, variables

```
x=1
c1=string1
c2=string2
c3=string3

echo $c1
string1
```

I'd like to have the output be `string1` by using something like:
`echo $(c($x))`

So later in the script I can increment the value of `x` and have it output `string1`, then `string2` and `string3`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use an array. Read `man bash`.

Comment: See [Indirect variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean) as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See the Bash FAQ: [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

To quote their example:

```
realvariable=contents
ref=realvariable
echo "${!ref}"   # prints the contents of the real variable
```

To show how this is useful for *your* example:

```
get_c() { local tmp; tmp="c$x"; printf %s "${!tmp}"; }
x=1
c1=string1
c2=string2
c3=string3
echo "$(get_c)"
```

If, of course, you want to do it the Right Way and just [use an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005):

```
c=( "string1" "string2" "string3" )
x=1
echo "${c[$x]}"
```

Note that these arrays are zero-indexed, so with `x=1` it prints `string2`; if you want `string1`, you'll need `x=0`.

Comment: excellent. After your edit it becomes crystal clear and my preferred choice. Thanks very much for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
eval echo \$c$x
```

Like others said, it makes more sense to use array in this case.

Comment: Using eval without doing appropriate quoting (as with `printf %q`) is quite dangerous from a security perspective, particularly if your script is handling any data which could potentially be made by malicious or untrusted processes. (Even a filename could be used to inject malicious content, if that's what you were looping over).

Answer (score 2):

if you have bash 4.0, you can use [associative arrays.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html). Or you can just use [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html). Another tool you can use is awk

eg

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  c[1]="string1"
  c[2]="string2"
  c[3]="string3"
  for(x=1;x<=3;x++){
    print c[x]
  }
}'
```