# Bash Script - Exclamation Point within Variable Reference

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm looking over a script (which has been used successfully in the past) which contains the following:

```
node=1
while :
do
    userKey=WEB_${node}_USER
    userVal=`echo ${!userKey}`
```

I have not been able to figure out why an exclamation point would be added to a variable reference like this. What purpose does "!" serve in this context?

It's rare for me to do much scripting so if I am missing any details please let me know and I will try to provide more information. I have not been able to find this answer elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `man bash` then search for `indirect  expansion`

Comment: possible duplicated [please see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain)

Comment: I much more wonder what purpose does `echo` here serve for. If you are rewriting the script, consider replacing that line it with `userVal="${!userKey}"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called indirect parameter expansion. Where `$userKey` expands to the value of the variable `userKey`, `${!userKey}` expands to the value of **the variable whose name is the value of** `userKey`. Since `usrKey` has the value `WEB_1_USER` (given the current value of `$node`, `${!userKey}` expands to the same result as `$WEB_1_USER`.

Its use is somewhat rare, since in many cases (including, it appears, here) an array `WEB_USER` of user names would be clearer than a set of numbered variables.

```
WEB_USER=(alice bob charlie)

node=1
while :
do
  userVal=${WEB_USER[node]}
```

Answer (score -1):

In bash, I thought that the only characters that retained their meta-character status inside double quotes were the dollar sign ($), the back-tick (`) and the backslash (\).

Comment: That's true but (a) irrelevant and (b) not an answer. (Irrelevant because the ! is part of a ${...} expansion, and the $'s metacharacter status is not in doubt.)