# How to test if a variable exists and has been initialized

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have to execute a function which has to test if a variable has been correctly defined in Bash and must use its associated value.

For instance, these variables are initialized at the top of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

var1_ID=0x04
var2_ID=0x05
var3_ID=0x06
var4_ID=0x09
```

I would like to call the script named *test* as follows:

```
./test var1
```

The current implemented function is:

```
function Get()
{
     if [ $1"_ID" != "" ]; then
         echo "here"
         echo $(($1_ID))
     else
         exit 0
     fi
}
```

I don't understand why I obtain `here` even if I enter `./test toto` or something else.

Do I need to use a specific command, such as [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)?

Comment: Related: [How to test if a variable is defined at all in Bash prior to version 4.2 with the nounset shell option?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56846/40596)

Comment: It seems no one has stated this, but `$1"_ID"` will evaluate to `"_ID"` if `$1` doesn't exist. And therefore will ALWAYS be `!= to ""`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to use indirect expansion: `${!variable}` and then `-n` to check if it has been defined:

The **indirect expansion** consists in calling a variable with another variable. That is, as the variable name may be changing, instead of saying `$a` we say `${!var}` and `var=a`.

```
$ cat a
var1_ID=0x04
var2_ID=0x05
var3_ID=0x06
var4_ID=0x09

for i in {1..5}; do
   v="var${i}_ID"
   if [ -n "${!v}" ]; then             # <-- this expands to varX_ID
      echo "$v set to value: ${!v}"
   else
      echo "$v not set"
   fi
done
```

If we execute, we get:

```
$ ./a
var1_ID set to value: 0x04
var2_ID set to value: 0x05
var3_ID set to value: 0x06
var4_ID set to value: 0x09
var5_ID not set
```

---

From `man test`:

> **-n** STRING
>
> the length of STRING is nonzero

Comment: Thank you fedorqui. However, I am not sur to understand. What means ${!v} ?

Comment: This is called **indirect expansion**. It consists in calling a variable with another variable. That is, as the variable name may be changing, instead of saying `$a` we say `${!var}` and `var=a`. You can read more in [bash: indirect expansion, please explain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8515411/1983854).

Comment: And, as fedorqui pointed out via [a related article](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56846/40596), you can test for whether something is _set_ using the expansion `${variable+string}`.

Answer (score 12):

Use *parameter* expansion:

```
: ${var:?}
```

Remove the colon if the empty string is a valid value (i.e., you only want to test for definedness).

```
: ${var?}
```

If you don't want the script to stop on the problem, you can use

```
if [[ ${var:+1} ]] ; then
    # OK...
else
    echo Variable empty or not defined. >&2
fi
```

Documented under *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`:

> When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below (e.g., `:-`), bash
> tests  for  a  parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting the colon results in a test only
> for a parameter that is unset.

> ```
> ${parameter:?word}
> ```
>
> Display  Error  if  Null or Unset.  If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of
> word (or a message to that effect if word is not present) is written to  the  standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the value of
> parameter is substituted.

> ```
> ${parameter:+word}
> ```
>
> Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` 4.2, you can use the `-v` operator in a conditional expression to test if a variable with the given name is set.

```
if [[ -v ${1}_ID ]]; then
    echo "${1}_ID is set"
    foo=${1}_ID
    echo "${!foo}"
fi
```

You still need indirect parameter expansion to get the value.

In `bash` 4.3 you can use a named reference to make working with it easier.

```
declare -n param=${1}_ID
if [[ -v param ]]; then
    echo "${1}_ID"
    echo "$param"
fi
```

(`param` will behave exactly like the variable it references. I don't know if there is an easy way, short of parsing the output of `declare -p param`, to get the name of the variable it references.)

Comment: What is "`_ID`"? A convention? A magic value? Perhaps explain it in the answer?

Comment: It's just the constant portion of the variable names that the OP is using. The assumption is that `$1` has a value like `var1`, `var2`, etc. `var1` and `_ID` together forms `var1_ID`, and that's the name of the variable whose existence we are testing for.