# how to iterate over multiple array in loop

Tags: bash

Following is my example.  I am trying to create a script that will do git clone + git pull. Now below i am trying to iterate 2nd array (A_modules) to check if any of repos folder is there or not, if not create it and then cd to it and do git pull. The problem is how do i use one of  1st array value as 2nd array name in variable to loop. on second for loop, the ${DIR[@]}; doesn't work !. Need to know how do i expand ${DIR[@]}  to ${A_modules[@]}.
I can do this easily with 3 for loop for 3 values in 1st array. but any smarter way to achieve this with the way i am trying.. Thanks a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_FOLDER=/opt/xyz
declare -a DIR_TOP=(A_modules customers C_modules)
declare -a A_modules=(python_repo java_repo perl_repo)
declare -a customers=(repo1 repo2 repo3)
declare -a C_modules=(xy_repo1 yz_repo2)

#GIT clone.
cd ${BASE_FOLDER}
for DIR in ${DIR_TOP[@]}; do
if [ ! -d "${DIR_TOP[$DIR]}" ]; then
    mkdir -p ${BASE_FOLDER}/${DIR}
fi

for REPO in ${DIR[@]}; do
    cd ${BASE_FOLDER}/${DIR_TOP[$DIR]}/
    if [ ! -d "${REPO]}" ]; then
            mkdir ${REPO}
            echo "Git cloning ${DIR_TOP[$DIR]} group repositorys: ${REPO} ..."
            git clone --branch 8.0 https://${GIT_USER}@${GIT_SERVER}/r/${DIR_TOP[$DIR]}/${REPO}.git
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should to use `tempVar` and next evaluate with `!`, review: [bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain)

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a DIR_TOP=(A_modules customers C_modules)
declare -a A_modules=(python_repo java_repo perl_repo)
declare -a customers=(repo1 repo2 repo3)
declare -a C_modules=(xy_repo1 yz_repo2)

for DIR in ${DIR_TOP[@]}; do
  echo "1: $DIR";
  tempVar="$DIR[@]";
  for REPO in ${!tempVar}; do
    echo "2: $REPO";
  done
done
```