# Bash script: select variable from array with highest value and output variable name, not value

Tags: bash

I have 50 variables that changes value all the time. Their values are integer e.g. 1-9999, but I don't know what the values are until the script runs.

I need to display the name of the variable with the highest value. The actual value is of no importance to me.

The variables are called Q1 - Q50.

Example:

```
Q34=22
Q1=23
Q45=3
Q15=99
```

Output must just say `Q15`

Could you please help me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using separate variables with numeric suffixes, rather than a real array? If you used a real array with elements `${Q[0]}`, `${Q[1]}` etc., this would be much easier.

Comment: @Tom: Using separate variables enables a solution without a loop, calling `set`.

Comment: I guess I can use elements Tom. as I said I am a noob so I dont see the light yet ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [variable indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/bash-indirect-expansion-please-explain) for this:

```
for var in Q{1..50}; do
    [[ ${!var} -gt $max ]] && max=$var
done
echo \$$max
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. Works like a charm and the least amount of code. Nice work and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for all vars and grep yours:

```
set | egrep "^Q[0-9]=|^Q[1-4][0-9]=|^Q50=" | sort -nt= -k2 | tail -1 | cut -d= -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, for example Q1-Q5

```
Q1=22
Q2=23
Q3=3
Q4=99
Q5=16

for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    name=Q$i
    value=${!name}
    echo "$name $value"
done  | sort -k2n | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

you get

> Q4

Comment: There's no need to use `eval` in `bash`.

Comment: How could I improve this?

Comment: See my or Josh Jolly's answer. You are using `eval` just to perform indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you here. Help is always appreciated you all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Run through each of the 50 variables using indirect variable expansion, then save the name whose value is the greatest.

```
for ((i=1; i<= 50; i++)); do
    name=Q$i
    value=${!name}
    if ((value > biggest_value)); then
        biggest_value=$value
        biggest_name=name
    fi
done

printf "%s has the largest value\n" "$biggest_name"
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner, I appreciate all the help.