# Using positional arguments in a bash script

Tags: bash, unix

This is my script `script.sh`:

```
Numbr_Parms=$#
a=`expr $Numbr_Parms - 2`
while [ $a -le $Numbr_Parms ]
do
    if [ "$a" =  "3" ]
    then
       PARAMSTRING="-param $3"
    else
       PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param $a"
    fi
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done
echo $PARAMSTRING
```

Running:

```
script.sh  username pass p1=v1 p2=v2 p3=v3
```

Expected output:

```
-param p1=v1 -param p2=v2 -param p3=v3
```

But i am getting: `$PARAMSTRING` as

```
-param p1=v1 -param 4 -param 5
```

Not sure what is the Issue with $4 and $5

Comment: Would you consider rewriting your script by using getopt and handling your options and parameters in a slightly different way to take advantage of getopt ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip the first two positional parameters, just use

```
for arg in "${@:3}"; do
    PARAMSTRING+="-param $arg "
done
```

The right way to build up a sequence of parameters, though, is to use an array, which will work even if one of the arguments itself contains whitespace.

```
for arg in "${@:3}"; do
    PARAMS+=(-param "$arg")
done

mycommand "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Comment: You may want to add a trailing space; otherwise, strings will overlap.

Comment: True. Actually, that also makes me wonder why I'm not using an array like I should be.

Comment: Try this: `set a b c d e; echo "${@:3}"`.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param $a"
```

You want to append the parameter in the position `a`. However, `$a` just holds the number. So to access `$1`, `$2`, etc you have to use [variable indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515492/1983854):

```
PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param ${!a}"
```

---

The full script can be reduced to a simple loop over the parameters, using `$#` as limit:

```
for ((i=3; i<=$#; i++)); do
        PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param ${!i}"
done
echo "$PARAMSTRING"
```

Or, even better, you can use an array like chepner shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37460792/1983854).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below line.

```
PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param $a"
```

In this the $a does not means the positional argument. It is a variable it have the 4, 5, like that only.

If you print that variable you will not get the positional argument. You get only 4, 5, 6 only.

So, you have to get the positional argument using that variable a.

Try the below step it will work as you expect.

```
Numbr_Parms=$#
a=`expr $Numbr_Parms - 2`
while [ $a -le $Numbr_Parms ]
do
    if [ "$a" =  "3" ]
    then
        PARAMSTRING="-param $3"
    else
        eval pos=\$$a    # This is the indirect reference to get the positional argument from variable a.
        PARAMSTRING="$PARAMSTRING -param $pos"
    fi
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done

echo $PARAMSTRING
```