# bash automatically select specific variable from while

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, while-loop

Is there a way to call a variable through the $i in a while loop? To access a specific variable automatically?

This is a scaled down version of what i'm trying to do:

```
i=1;

while [ $i -lt 4 ]; do
    let card$i=1;
    let i++;
done

let i=1;

while [[ $i -lt 4 ]]; do

    if [ "$card$i" = "1" ]; then 
        let card$i++;
    fi

    let i++;
done
```

Is there a way to make this work?

(I'm trying to do this with +50 variables. This is just scaled down)

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for [indirect expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8515492/1983854).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, that you want to increment 50 variables every loop? If so you can use indirect expansion although i would suggest saving yourself possible trouble down the line and just using an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *nameref* variable (supported starting from Bash 4.3):

> A variable can be assigned the *nameref* attribute using the `-n`
>   option to the `declare` or `local`  builtin commands  to create a
>   *nameref*, or a reference to another variable.  This allows variables to be manipulated indirectly.  Whenever the *nameref* variable is 
>   referenced  or  assigned to, the operation is actually performed on
>   the variable specified by the *nameref* variable's value.  A *nameref*
>   is commonly used within shell functions to refer to  a  variable whose
>   name is passed as an argument to the function.  For instance, if a
>   variable name is passed to a shell function as its first argument,
>   running
>
> ```
> declare -n ref=$1
> ```
>
> inside the function creates a *nameref* variable *ref* whose value is
>   the variable  name  passed  as  the first  argument.   References and
>   assignments to `ref` are treated as references and assignments to the
>   variable whose name was passed as `$1`.  If the  control  variable  in
>   a  for  loop  has  the  *nameref* attribute,  the  list  of words can
>   be a list of shell variables, and a name reference will be established
>   for each word in the list, in turn, when the loop is  executed. Array 
>   variables  cannot  be given  the  `-n`  attribute. However, *nameref*
>   variables can reference array variables and subscripted array
>   variables.  *Nameref*s can be unset using the `-n` option to  the 
>   `unset`  builtin. Otherwise,  if `unset`  is executed with the name of
>   a *nameref* variable as an argument, the variable referenced by the
>   *nameref* variable will be unset.

Thus you can make your code work as follows:

```
i=1;

while [ $i -lt 4 ]; do
    let card$i=1;
    let i++;
done

let i=1;

while [[ $i -lt 4 ]]; do

    declare -n cardref=card$i
    if [ "$cardref" = "1" ]; then 
        let cardref++;
    fi

    let i++;
done
```

---

For bash versions before 4.3 you can do the following:

```
i=1;

while [ $i -lt 4 ]; do
    let card$i=1;
    let i++;
done

let i=1;

while [[ $i -lt 4 ]]; do

    cardref=card$i
    if [ "${!cardref}" = "1" ]; then 
        let $cardref++;
    fi

    let i++;
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i really appreciate it! but when i run it i get this: "./test: line 14: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]"

Comment: @andr8076 Which version of bash do you use?

Comment: "version 3.2.57(1)-release" ;)

Comment: @andr8076 I added to my answer the solution for older versions of bash.

Comment: WOW that is amazing! Thank you very much!