# How to print script parameters sequentially?

Tags: bash, echo

My shell name is **test.sh**, and I want to output all parameters which are passed to test.sh , but I find my code can't work well.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
num=$#
while [ $i -le $num ]; do
    echo $($i)
    ((i++))
done
```

When I run `./test.sh -a -b -c`, my expected output is:

```
-a
-b
-c
```

but, it tells me

```
./test.sh: line 5: 1: command not found
./test.sh: line 5: 2: command not found
./test.sh: line 5: 3: command not found
```

How can I resolve this issue and output all parameters using `echo` command?

Comment: `echo $i` just output `1 2 3`, but my expectation is `-a -b -c`.

Comment: Actually, I want to use `echo $($i)` to achieve the same result with `echo $1 $2 $3`, but I find `echo $($i)` is an invalid command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [variable indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515492/1983854):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
num=$#
while [ $i -le $num ]; do
    echo ${!i}         # <--- print the content of $1, $2...
    ((i++))
done
```

Upon execution, this returns:

```
$ bash test.sh -a -b "-c d"
-a
-b
-c d
```

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and *parameter* is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as indirect expansion. If parameter is a *nameref*, this expands to the name of the variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

If you wish to make it more verbose, show the mapping of `${1..n}` to its value:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
num=$#
while [ $i -le $num ]; do
    printf "$%s = %s\n" "$i" "${!i}"
    ((i++))
done
```

See the output:

```
$ bash test.sh -a -b "-c d"
$1 = -a
$2 = -b
$3 = -c d
```

Comment: a shell expert, this resolve my issue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash the sequence `$(...)` is to create a sub-shell to execute a command. It's a "new" way of using backticks.

The expression

```
$($i)
```

is equivalent to

```
`$i`
```

So what you are doing is calling the arguments as a command in a sub-shell.

Comment: So he is trying to run `1`, `2` and `3` as commands, which are not. Nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a one-line script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $*
```