# Using a string value with the name of an existing variable to get the value of the existing variable

Tags: bash

I am using a bash script in an azure devops pipeline where a variable is created dynamically from one of the pipeline tasks.

I need to use the variable's value in subsequent scripts, I can formulate the string which is used for the variable name, however cannot get the value of the variable using this string. I hope the below example makes it clear on what I need.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
PartAPartB="This is my text"
echo "$PartAPartB" #Shows "This is my text" as expected

#HOW DO I GET BELOW TO PRINT "This is my text"
#without using the PartAPartB variable and 
#using VarAB value to become the variable name

VarAB="PartAPartB"
VARNAME="$VarAB" 
echo $("$VARNAME") #INCORRECT
```

Comment: I suggest `echo "${!VARNAME}"`.

Comment: See: [Accessing indirect shell variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43991626/3776858)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing indirect shell variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991626/accessing-indirect-shell-variables-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to do this

```
$ PartAPartB="This is my text"
$ VarAB="PartAPartB"
$ eval "echo \${${VarAB}}"
This is my text
```

Comment: `eval` has security implications, it's best to avoid it.

Comment: `eval` is one-character away from `evil`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices with bash. Using a *nameref* with `declare -n` (which is the preferred approach for Bash >= 4.26) or using *variable indirection*. In your case, examples of both would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

VarAB="PartAPartB"

## using a nameref
declare -n VARNAME=VarAB
echo "$VARNAME"           # CORRECT

## using indirection
othervar=VarAB
echo "${!othervar}"       # Also Correct
```

(**note:** do not use `ALLCAPS` variable names, those a generally reserved for environment variables or system variables)