# Bash substitution inside substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning bash, and wanted to do something very simple, here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#read-multiple: reads multiple values from keyboard

echo -n "Enter one or more values:"
read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5

for i in {1..5}
do
    echo var$i= ${var"$i"}
done
```

In the `for` loop I am trying to print to values entered by the user, only at the `echo`line I get the error:

```
${var"$i"}: bad substitution
```

What I was expecting to happen is:

1. `$i` expands to the current value between 1 and 5 (say 1 for example)
2. `${var"$i"}` expands to ${var1} which expands to the value of var1

This is not the case apparently...Could you explain to me why that is ? does bash expand everything on the line at once?

I have also tried `${var${$i}}` and `$var${$i}` but both give the same error...why is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for v in var{1..5}; do
  echo $v = ${!v}
done
```

or

```
for i in {1..5}; do
  v="var$i"
  echo $v = ${!v}
done
```

See this post:

- [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)

Documentation here:

- [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: What I want to do is actually use the `var1, var2...` isn't there a way o use the value of `$i` in the naming of the variable I would use at each loop iteration ?