# How to read properties file in Unix script where key is in another user input variable

Tags: bash, unix

I have below property file in same directory.

`cancellation.properties`

Content:

```
TestData=My Name
```

My unix script is `abc.sh`

Content:

```
#!/bin/ksh
. ./cancellation.properties

echo  "Please enter data to read"

read data

echo $data
```

While running I give the value `TestData`.

I am getting output as `"TestData"`.

But I want output as `"My Name"`.  What changes needs to be done here because key will be entered by user.

Comment: ksh is not the same as bash

Comment: I'm assuming the space in `My Name` is a problem.

Comment: `TestData="My Name"` is the right way to do it, as seen in @Cyrus' solution.  See this related post as well: [What is indirect expansion in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use awk to get this.

In place of your `echo $data` put:

```
awk -F"=" -v data=$data '$1==data{print $2}' cancellation.properties
```

Which says "Split each record in your cancellation.properties file by an equal sign. If the first field is the value in variable `$data` (which is the variable `data` in your awk script set by that `-v` flag since you can't use shell variables directly in `awk`) then output the second field.

Also, now that read your question more thoroughly, it looks like you are including your `.properties` file at the top of the script. This may not be the best answer for you if you wish to proceed. See @cyrus comment to your question where it's noted to quote your variable assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

. <(awk -F '=' '{print $1 "=\""$2"\""}' file)

echo  "Please enter data to read"
read data
echo "${!data}"
```

Output:

```
My Name
```

Comment: I used --   <(awk -F '=' '{print $1 "=\""$2"\""}' ./cancellation.properties)   But this not working getting output as data.

Answer (score 0):

If there's the possibility that you might want other configuration data read from a file, I'd suggest treating your properties file like a config rather than an embedded script, and putting your data into a structure dedicated to storing configuration. Like an array. Something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A canprop=()

while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    [[ $key = #* ]] && continue      # handle comments
    canprop[$key]="$value"
done < cancellation.properties

printf '> %s\n' "${canprop[TestData]}"
```

Note that this particular solution doesn't work if `$key` is repeated within the configuration file -- the last key read will "win". But it saves you the hassle of putting everything into your "main" namespace.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need to store the variables, and only want to display the value, you can do like this:

```
read -p "Please enter data to read: " data
grep "^${data}=" ./cancellation.properties | cut -d"=" -f2-
```