# How to get value of variable nested in same config file in unix shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have config file where variables are defined

```
A=b c d
b=BALL
c=CAT
d=DOG
```

This is my script:

```
for word in $A
do
    for config in $word
    do
        echo $config
    done
    echo "End of nested for loop"
done
```

Above prints

```
b
c
d
```

I need values of b c and d

```
Ball
CAT 
DOG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

A="b c d"
b=BALL
c=CAT
d=DOG


for word in $A
do
    for config in $word
    do
        echo ${!config}
    done
    echo "End of nested for loop"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the variable that is pointed by your variable, not your variable itself:

```
for word in $A
do
    for config in ${!word}
    do
        echo $config
    done
    echo "End of nested for loop"
done
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean) you can find more information

Answer (score 1):

You logically only have a single loop, not a nested one, so you also should implement only a single loop:

```
for variable in $A
do
  echo "${!variable}"
done
```

Btw, you will need to have quotes around the assignment with spaces if you simply execute it in the bash:

```
A='a b c'
```