# Unable to use constant value in a variable

Tags: shell

I am writing a small script in shell and I have a constant in upper cases as you can see in code ('*PRIX*'). My problem is, I would like to print the value of the constant using the variable that will be equal to the string ('*PRIX*'). I won't explain you why as it would be useless, but that would cut my entire code in half and simplify everything.

---

```
readonly _PRIX_=7
.
.
.

function trier {

#here it starts
#function call, change 'option' value for "_PRIX_"
option=$(equivalence "$option")

#HERE The line I need to fix to print '7' 
echo $'$option'

#Print '7', What I wanna recreate knowing 'option' value=="_PRIX_"
echo $_PRIX_ 

sort -t$":" -k'$option' "$le_depot"

}
```

Comment: `main.sh: line 7: equivalence: command not found` `sort: invalid number at field start: invalid count at start of ‘$option’`. Doesn't `readonly _PRIX_=7; echo "$_PRIX_";` work?

Comment: What is `option` set to?  Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: 'option' is a variable and it will be equal to the string '_PRIX_' but '_PRIX_' is also a constant and I wanna print '_PRIX_' value wich is '7' by using the variable calde 'option'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bash, indirection might help you.  For example:

```
readonly _PRIX=7
option=PRIX
option_var=_$option
echo "${!option_var}" # outputs 7
```

Related:

- [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/6862601)
- [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8515411/6862601)

Comment: That's it!! thanks a lot. Can you explain me what u did approximatly, I have never seen that before? :)

Comment: Please take a look at he related posts for more info.