# How to combine two strings and use it as a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, combinations

Need to find a way to locate desired variables based on string combination

```
#!/bin/bash
DSPDSP="1234"
$A="DSP"
$B="DSP"
PORTLIST=$A$B
echo $PORTLIST
```

DSPDSP

I hope there is a smart function in bash that concerts a string into variable name

```
smart_echo $PORTLIST
```

1234

Comment: I think you are looking for a kind of indirect expansion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
smart_echo() {
    local varname="$1"
    echo "${!varname}"
}

DSPDSP="1234"
A="DSP"
B="DSP"
PORTLIST="$A$B"
smart_echo "$PORTLIST"

=> 1234
```

If your bash version is 4.3 or newer, you can also say as an alternative:

```
smart_echo() {
    declare -n p="$1"
    echo "$p"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, based on your input, I found my working version like this:
    A="DSP"
    B="DSP"
    PORTLIST=$A$B
    echo ${!PORTLIST}
=> 1234

Comment: Yep. It woks without defining a special function. BTW please make it a practice to **double-quote variables** with a few exceptions (the case an explict word-splitting is required, the pattern matching (regex or comparison) within [[ ... ]], etc.). BR.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, based on your input, I found my working version like this:

```
    A="DSP" 
    B="DSP"
    PORTLIST=$A$B 
    echo ${!PORTLIST}
```

=> 1234

Comment: Use a *nameref*, e.g. `declare -n PLIST=$A$B; echo $PLIST`. See `"nameref"` in [bash(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)