# How to add called variable as a suffix to another variable and then call the suffixed variable?

Tags: linux, bash

My script:

```
for (( i=1; i <= $j; i++ ))
do
list_$i = $i
echo "$list_$i"
done
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
etc
```

I have a problem with the `echo` statement while calling the variable.

Please help me on this.

Comment: what's the current output?

Comment: Use an array: `list[i]=$i ; echo "${list[i]}"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `$j` has an nonnegative integral value,

```
for (( i=1; $i<=$j; i=$i+1 ))
do
    list[$i]=$i
    echo "${list[$i]}"
done
```

Bash *arrays* are used, whereby `$list` is a single structure, a Bash array.

Answer (score 1):

First remember that a variable assignment is without spaces around the `=`.
What you are trying to do, is possible but complicated.

```
for (( i=1; i <= 6; i++ )); do 
   source <(echo "list_$i=$i")
   varname=list_$i
   echo "${!varname}"
done
```

You can also view the results in a different loop

```
for result in list_{1..6}; do
   echo "${result}=${!result}"
done
```