# Bash - How to get the value of a var with name from another var

Tags: bash

Sorry if it's a dumb q, but I couldn't find the answer!
if I have var 1:

```
STR="hello"
```

var 2:

```
letter="T"
```

I want:

```
echo ${S${letter}R}
```

to get "hello", but instead I get bad substitution, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STR="hello"
letter="T"
x="S${letter}R"   # concat string in new variable
echo "${!x}"
```

Output:

```
hello
```

---

See: [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8515411/3776858)

Comment: First of, thank you for your help!
Is it possible to do it in one command? I can't use temp var as x

Comment: `eval echo "\${S${letter}R}"`?