# Get the value from secret variables in GitLab when concatenated with other variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have variable name URL_DEV in Gitlab Variables (Settings > CI/CD > Variables). I want to get the value using ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}. 
Example : echo URL_${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME} should provide the value from Gitlab Variables, but it is giving output as URL_DEV but not printing the value.

```
#Tried below commands
$ echo $URL_${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
output: DEV

$APP="URL_${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"
echo $APP
output: URL_DEV

$APP="URL_${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"
echo $(echo $APP)
output: URL_DEV
```

Expected Output should be value from the variables

```
echo $URL_${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
expected output: https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [bash indirect expension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515492/2653911). This snippet works :

```
URL_DEV="https://google.com"
ENV="DEV"
SITE="URL_"$ENV
echo $SITE
URL_DEV

curl -k ${!SITE}

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still looking for the answer to this question.

If there is a secret gitlab variable called something like the following `COMPUTE_VAR_dev`
and within that variable is the contents of a secret `.yml` file (for instance) - (see image)

[image]

That variable can then be accessed within another variable, such as the following

```
variables:
   ENV: dev
   COMPUTE_VAR: '${COMPUTE_VAR_${ENV}}'
script:
   - echo $COMPUTE_VAR > vars.yml
```

The content of the variable will now be created as file named `vars.yml` file on the runner

One can then do something nice like the following

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      variables:
        ENV: "prod"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
      variables:
        ENV: "stage"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
        ENV: "dev"
    - when: always
deploy:
  variables:
    COMPUTE_VAR: '${COMPUTE_VAR_${ENV}}'
  script:
   - echo $COMPUTE_VAR > vars.yml
   - echo 'deploy something here - with the new file'
```

Hope it helps