# How to use a passed parameter to call its value as a global variable in Bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function which will take 2 parameters. 1st a color name, 2nd text to be printed.
I have also declared variables for colors as global variables. I want to expand the values by using 1st parameter string.

For now I am using switch case which is the worst way to do it I believe.
Thank you in advance

```
red=$'\e[1;31m'
grn=$'\e[1;32m'
yel=$'\e[1;33m'
blu=$'\e[1;34m'
mag=$'\e[1;35m'
cyn=$'\e[1;36m'
end=$'\e[0m'

Print() {
    # I want to use 1st parameter to call the variables above
    # i.e. if red is passed, then i want value of red which is '\e[1;31m'
    printf $((${1}))
    printf "$2"
    printf $end
}
```

**function call**

Print red "string"

Comment: To the OP: Please ignore the downvotes on all 3 answers; the votes do not reflect the correctness of any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to indirect parameter expansion.

```
Print() {
    printf ${!1}
    printf "$2"
    printf $end
}
```

However, a safer way to write this is with

```
Print() {
  printf '%s%s%s' "${!1}" "$2" "$end"
}
```

This ensures you get the expected output even if one of the two arguments (the second in particular) contains a `%`.

---

Depending on how many other contexts use your color variables, I would move the escape handling into `Print` itself, so that you can simply define `red=31`, for example.

```
Print() {
  printf '\033[1;%sm%s\033[0m' "${!1}" "$2"
}
```

Comment: Hey @chepner

thank you for the simplified version. But I checked what you said in first comment, I added "%" in the string and kept the Print function as it is. I didn't have any affect in the output. Maybe I didn't understand it correctly. Can you clarify?

Comment: As as simple example, try `foo="%s"; printf "$foo"`. You'll get no output, rather than the literal output `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make bash interpret a string as a variable with ${!...}.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

red=$'\e[1;31m'
grn=$'\e[1;32m'
yel=$'\e[1;33m'
blu=$'\e[1;34m'
mag=$'\e[1;35m'
cyn=$'\e[1;36m'
end=$'\e[0m'

Print() {
    # I want to use 1st parameter to call the variables above
    # i.e. if red is passed, then i want value of red which is '\e[1;31m'
    echo -n ${!1}
    printf "$2"
    printf $end
}

Print "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try indirect expansion:  [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)

Here's your function with indirect expansion:

```
red=$'\e[1;31m'
grn=$'\e[1;32m'
yel=$'\e[1;33m'
blu=$'\e[1;34m'
mag=$'\e[1;35m'
cyn=$'\e[1;36m'
end=$'\e[0m'

Print() {
    # I want to use 1st parameter to call the variables above
    # i.e. if red is passed, then i want value of red which is '\e[1;31m'
    echo "${!1}$2$end"
}

Print red hello
```