# What is invalid indirect expansion and why does it prevent me from installing this program?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, wget

I'm trying to install the Nasa OpenSatKit on my computer. It is a Ubuntu 20.04 distribution of Linux. When I try to install I receive this command:

```
/dev/fd/63: line 16: OPEN_SAT_KIT_PATH: invalid indirect expansion
```

I install it using this wget command: 
bash `<(\wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenSatKit/OpenSatKit/vendor/install.sh`

Also, it says that line 16 is the problem. I looked at line 16 for the installation and here are the first 18 lines: 
`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OPEN_SAT_KIT_VERSION="2.2.0"
BASE_DIR="$(pwd)"

# Intentional order: OSK Archive, Dependencies, COSMOS, Build System 
# - Dependencies cover OSK's needs, COSMOS may need additional ones
# - OSK last ensures OSK COSMOS config files not overrriden

main()
{

announce "INSTALLATION WILL TAKE TIME AND INCLUDES PROMPTS!"

# set default path unless environment var exists
if [ ! -n "${!OPEN_SAT_KIT_PATH}" ]; then
   OPEN_SAT_KIT_PATH="`pwd`/OpenSatKit-master/"
fi
```

`

Note that line 16 is " if [ ! -n "${!OPEN_SAT_KIT_PATH}" ]; then " .
Can someone help me install this please or tell me why it isn't working?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Just post the text instead.

Comment: Sorry I'll update it right now.

Comment: TBH the indirection expansions seems like a typo here. Try removing the `!`. Ie. change `${!OPEN...` into `${OPEN...`

Comment: I've edited it so there are no more images. The code for the installation is also available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenSatKit/OpenSatKit/vendor/install.sh

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried that and the installation is currently proceeding. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a typo here. I guess the code was supposed to check if the variable is not set and if it isn't, assign some default value to it. Remove the `!`.

More about indirect expansion could be found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean) and in [bash manual shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the present version of OpenSatKit, particularly COSMOS, is incompatible with Ubuntu 20.04.  Consider installing it with Ubuntu 18.4 LTS.