# Values in a sbatch --array command different from the job task IDs, each of them run in a different job

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, jobs, slurm, sbatch

Is it possible to feed a script some values in the sbatch --array command line **different from the job task IDs**, and each of them be run in a different job?

```
sbatch --array=1-2 script.sh 4 6
```

with script.sh being

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE=$"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"

echo $VALUE
```

then, after they have run,

```
cat slurm*
```

returns

```
1
2
```

But I wonder whether it is possible to make the 2 jobs return instead the "4 6" values fed in the sbatch --array command, one apiece:

```
4
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indirect variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean):

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE=${!SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}

echo $VALUE
```

Note the exclamation mark. After

```
sbatch --array=1-2 script.sh 4 6
```

you should have two output files, one with `4` and one with `6`.