# How to make the number result to a string with value in it

Tags: linux, shell

I want to get some number, and assign the result to a custom string。I want to get numbers and I can use it in the next part of this script

the name of this cript is calQue.sh. the content of it is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

lsfDir=/opt/ibm/lsf/10.1/linux3.10-glibc2.17-x86_64/bin

Queue="ser short medium large"

for i in $Queue
do
  queName=`echo $i"idleNum"`
  $queName"idleNum"=`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i | grep ok | awk '{if($5==0) print $0}' | wc -l`
done

echo $seridleNum
```

I ran it,

```
sh calQue.sh
```

and it is wrong. the result i got is:

```
calQue.sh: line 14: seridleNumidleNum=1: command not found
calQue.sh: line 14: shortidleNumidleNum=7: command not found
calQue.sh: line 14: mediumidleNumidleNum=37: command not found
calQue.sh: line 14: largeidleNumidleNum=4: command not found
```

So i tried other ways like:

```
for i in $Queue
do
  queName=`echo $i`
  idleNum=`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i | grep ok | awk '{if($5==0) print $0}' | wc -l`

  #`echo $i`Num=$idleNum   //it is wrong

  #$queName=$idleNum       //it is wrong
```

done

and

```
Queue="ser short medium large"

for i in $Queue
do
  queName=`echo $i`
  "$i"idleNum=`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i | grep ok | awk '{if($5==0) print $0}' | wc -l`
   echo $"$i"idleNum  //it is wrong
done
```

How do i can get correct result, for example:

string  seridleNumidleNum should be equal 1;

I find it is right when the string without variable $i

```
idleNum=`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i | grep ok | awk '{if($5==0) print $0}' | wc -l`
echo $idleNum
```

Comment: `bhosts` isn't standard POSIX shell, it looks like an IBM related command, e.g. [bhosts](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=reference-bhosts). Have you consulted that documentation?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it is nothing about bhosts, see my update.

Comment: Can you post the actual script? `"calQue.sh: line 14:"` -- what you posted only has 13 lines so we are missing something... That appears to be the result of `$queName"idleNum"=\`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i ...` -- which obviously won't be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to store the result to a variable which has the name as the string value e.g seridleNumidleNum. By default the shell will execute the command which definitely leads to the  **not found** issue. A correct way is to put it into `eval` command

```
eval $queName"idleNum"=`$lsfDir/bhosts hg_$i | grep ok | awk '{if($5==0) print $0}' | wc -l`
```

`((expression))` can be used as an alternative

> ((expression))
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the
> expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return
> status is  1

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `bash`, a better approach than trying to generate variable names at runtime is to use an *associative array* to store values. For example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

lsfDir=/opt/ibm/lsf/10.1/linux3.10-glibc2.17-x86_64/bin

# Make idleNum an associative array
declare -A idleNum

# Note using a regular array here instead of a single string that relies on
# shell word splitting
Queue=(ser short medium large)

for i in "${Queue[@]}"
do
  # No need to use grep or wc here; awk can do it all.
  idleNum[$i]=$("$lsfDir/bhosts" "hg_$i" | awk '/ok/ && $5==0 { c++ } END { print c+0 }')
done

printf "%s\n" "${idleNum[ser]}"
```

---

If you can't use associative arrays for some reason (Like being stuck on an ancient version of `bash`), [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare) is better than `eval` for building a variable name, as it avoids [a bunch of potential issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/9952196) with evaluating an arbitrary string:

```
declare "${i}idleNum=$("$lsfDir/bhosts" "hg_$i" | awk '/ok/ && $5==0 { c++ } END { print c+0 }')"
```

To get the value of a variable with a name that is constructed at runtime, you can use [indirect expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8515411/9952196):

```
i=ser
name="${i}idleNum"
printf "%s\n" "${!name}"
```

---

See also [Why is `$(...)` preferred over backticks?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) from the bash FAQ.

On a related note, it's a good idea to run scripts through https://www.shellcheck.net/ to find many potential issues.