# Unable to get the value of variable inside a variable in azure pipelines

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use variables inside variables in azure pipelines.
Below is an example of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

customer=google
environment=preprod
android_google_preprod_account_activation_url=preprod.google.com

echo "Customer is $customer"
echo "Environment is $environment"

var1=android_${customer}_${environment}_account_activation_url

echo "variable is $var1"
echo "original value is ${!var1}"
```

I get the expected output for the above bash script when I run it on my Ubuntu server, with NO errors:

```
Customer is google
Environment is preprod
variable is android_google_preprod_account_activation_url
original value is preprod.google.com
```

The yml code for azure pipelines is:

```
parameters:
  - name: customer
    displayName: 'select customer'
    type: string
    values:
      - google
  - name: environment
    displayName: 'select environment'
    type: string
    values:
      - preprod

variables:
  - group: android-${{ parameters.customer }}-${{ parameters.environment }}
  - name: var1
    value: android-${{ parameters.customer }}-${{ parameters.environment }}-account-activation-url

script: |
      echo "Customer is $(customer)"
      echo "Environment is $(environment)"
      echo "variable is $(var1)"
      echo "original value is $(!var1)"
    displayName: 'echo variables'
```

The value of android-google-preprod-account-activation-url is being taken from variable groups inside library.

It gives me an error for the 4th line:

```
invalid indirect expansion
```

The first 3 lines output is as expected.

Expected output is:

```
Customer is google
Environment is preprod
variable is android_google_preprod_account_activation_url
original value is preprod.google.com
```

Is there a different syntax that needs to be followed in azure pipelines?

Comment: Does it support indirect expension ? It seems it was added to bash 4.3: _This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.3-beta, and the
previous version, bash-4.3-alpha._ [changelog](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES) EDIT: I may be wrong on the version. The changelog is not very clear.

Comment: I notice that you have in your Azure script `$(!var1)` instead of `${!var1}`. In addition to this, I suggest that in your pipeline you also do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` to verify the bash version used by Azure. AFIK, indirect expansion works properly from bash 4.4 on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro syntax "**`$(varName)`**" is a proprietary syntax in Azure Pipelines to interpolate variable values. It is processed during runtime and different with the syntax "**`${varName}`**" in Bash scripts.

For your case, you can try to use the compile time syntax "**`${{ variables.varName }}`**" to get the value in the pipeline.

```bash
echo "original value is $(${{ variables.var1 }})"
```

With above change, after you triggered the pipeline:

- At the compile time, the expression "**`${{ variables.var1 }}`**" will be replaced with the actual value "**`android_google_preprod_account_activation_url`**". So, the expression "**`$(${{ variables.var1 }})`**" will be changed to "**`$(android_google_preprod_account_activation_url)`**".
- Then at the runtime, the expression will be parsed as the correct value "**`preprod.google.com`**".

Below is an example I have tested on my side.

###### YAML

```yaml
variables:
  android_google_preprod_account_activation_url: 'preprod.google.com'
  var1: 'android_google_preprod_account_activation_url'

jobs:
- job: A
  displayName: 'Job A'
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Print variables'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "android_google_preprod_account_activation_url = $(android_google_preprod_account_activation_url)"
        echo "var1 = $(var1)"
        echo "original value = $(${{ variables.var1 }})"
```

###### Result

[image]

For more details, you can reference the related document "[**Understand variable syntax**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)".

Comment: Hi @AbdulMajeed, You're welcome, and glad that my answer can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I`m not a bash expert ))) however... you're trying to use the parameters expansion [What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515411/what-is-indirect-expansion-what-does-var-mean)

But it refers to the bash variables.... when you define variables in the devops pipeline, you have to use them as [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) or through the [macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

or something like that:

```
android_google_preprod_account_activation_url=preprod.google.com

echo "Customer is $(customer)"
echo "Environment is $(environment)"

var1=android_$(customer)_$(environment)_account_activation_url

echo "variable is $var1"
echo "original value is ${!var1}"
```