# Concatenating variables in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, string-concatenation

I am trying to add a variable to the middle of a variable, so for instance in PHP I would do this:

```
$mystring = $arg1 . '12' . $arg2 . 'endoffile';
```

so the output might be `20121201endoffile`, how can I achieve the same in a linux bash script?

Comment: Have you read [bash-script-variable-inside-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634590/bash-script-variable-inside-variable) ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try doing this, there's no special character to concatenate in bash :

```
mystring="${arg1}12${arg2}endoffile"
```

### explanations

If you don't put brackets, you will ask [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to concatenate `$arg112 + $argendoffile` (I guess that's not what you asked) like in the following example :

```
mystring="$arg112$arg2endoffile"
```

The brackets are *delimiters* for the variables when needed. When not needed, you can use it or not.

### another solution

(less portable : require `bash` > 3.1)

```
$ arg1=foo
$ arg2=bar
$ mystring="$arg1"
$ mystring+="12"
$ mystring+="$arg2"
$ mystring+="endoffile"
$ echo "$mystring"
foo12barendoffile
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/013

Comment: Using curly braces as delimiters is a super-helpful tip, thanks!