# Using an iterating variable in command-line script to create file names

Tags: batch-file, command-line, adb

I'm trying to automate an adb test procedure using a batch file. After each run a file, `.CloudData.txt` is made. I want to preface that file name with a trial number, `T1.CloudData.txt`, etc. I made this test code:

```
echo off
set /p loops="Enter a number of iterations: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,%loops%) do (
    set file=//scard//mytest//T%%i.CloudData.txt
    echo %file%
)
```

So that eventually I can have something along the lines of:

```
echo off
set /p loops="Enter a number of iterations: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,%loops%) do (
    rem Execute adb commands for test
    set file=//scard//mytest//T%%i.CloudData.txt
    adb shell mv /sdcard/mytest/.CloudData.txt file
)
```

But the test returns, assuming `loops` = 3, `/sdcard/mytest/T3.CloudData.txt` 3 times. To be painfully specific, the number stored in `loops` is being added where `%%i` should be. From what I've read in the following post: [bash script variable inside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634590/bash-script-variable-inside-variable), I think I should be using an array, but that's impractical if one day I have to run the test for more than iterations than the array permits. How should I proceed?

Comment: Just a note: This is not PowerShell but actually Command Shell. You should edit your title and tags to target your question to the right people!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's not ***bash*** either, its ***batch***. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks, and again, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p loops="Enter a number of iterations: "
for /l %%i in (1,1,%loops%) do (
    rem Execute adb commands for test
    set file=//scard//mytest//T%%i.CloudData.txt
    adb shell mv /sdcard/mytest/.CloudData.txt !file!
)
```

The reason for `%%i` seems to be `3` at all three times (it isn't) is the variable `%file%`, which was left from a previous run of your script

Comment: Thank you very much! If you wouldn't mind, could you explain the how calling `!file!` differs from calling `%file%`?

Comment: @alwaysthestudent Please read number one batch issue [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) the sligthest research effort would have revealed this.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, it was enlightening; I'm sorry for wasting your time.